# Search JSON Parsed MySQL Data using user input

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, html, intel-xdk

Hi I'm building a HTML5 App to display data from remote MySQL.

Right now the following code able to fetch data and display in the app.

I also have 2 dropdown in my app to filter the results. How I can get the dropdown to filter the JSON Parsed data?

HTML

```
//Filter input box/dropdown
<form>
Title:<br>
<input type="text" name="title"><br>
City:<br>
<input type="text" name="city">
</form> 

<div id="id01"></div>
```

My JS

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost/mysql.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
var i;
var out = "<table>";

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" +
    arr[i].title +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].City +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].level +
    "</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>";
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: filter based on what?

Comment: Strategy: 
Step 1. Get the filter value from the input element. 
Step 2. Search the value of the input element in the parsed JSON.

Tip: Do it right after that you've done `JSON.parse(response)`.

Comment: @e4c5 For example search or filter based on title.

Comment: @Anson, any example appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before we start, let me mention about something I modified.

1. I added `id`s on the both `input` elements.
2. I created a new `originalJSONArr` for below example.

Ok, let's go!

**About HTML**

The `input` element is interactive and it has [**input** event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input). That means we can use **input** event for trigger event; do something when users type anything in `input` element. So, I added `id`s for identitying each input.

```
Title:<br>
<input id="title" type="text" name="title"><br>
City:<br>
<input id="city" type="text" name="city">
```

**About JavaScript**

I like functional programming and you can see functions which are for each implement. As you can see, `addEventListeners` is to add event on elements, `titleEvent` and `cityEvent` are the callback function are executed when the event has been fired.

In addition, there is `filterJSON` function is to be defined by you. It's not difficult! `filterJSON(values);` is the statement to execute `filterJSON` function with `values` parameter. So you can use the modified `values` parameter as local variable in `filterJSON` function.

```
function addEventListeners(filterJSON) {
  var titleInput = document.getElementById('title'), // Get element.
      cityInput = document.getElementById('city'),
      values = {};

  function titleEvent() {
    values.title = this.value; // Get element value.
    filterJSON(values); // Execute callback function 'filterJSON'.
  }

  function cityEvent() {
    values.city = this.value;
    filterJSON(values);
  }

  titleInput.addEventListener('input', titleEvent); // Bind event listener with 'input' event and 'titleEvent' function.

  cityInput.addEventListener('input', cityEvent);
}
```

The last part is do the purpose! You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) approach to lead to our goal. See as below.

```
var originalJSONArr = [
  {
    title: 'Taiwan',
    city: 'Taipei City'
  },
  {
    title: 'Taiwan',
    city: 'Taichung'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'New York'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'Chicago'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'Miami'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'Boston'
  }
];

addEventListeners(
  function(values) { // This is the 'filterJSON' callback as mentioned.
    var filteredJSON = originalJSONArr.filter(function(item) {
      return (item.title === values.title || item.city === values.city);
    });
    // You can do anything with filteredJSON as of here.
    console.log(filteredJSON);
  }
);
```

**About Example**

Now, try the following snippet! Type `Taiwan` in `title` input and you'll see the objects whose `title` are `Taiwan`. Or enter a specific city name in `city` input.

```js
function addEventListeners(filterJSON) {
  var titleInput = document.getElementById('title'), // Get element.
      cityInput = document.getElementById('city'),
      values = {};

  function titleEvent() {
    values.title = this.value; // Get element value.
    filterJSON(values); // Execute callback function 'filterJSON'.
  }
  
  function cityEvent() {
    values.city = this.value;
    filterJSON(values);
  }
  
  titleInput.addEventListener('input', titleEvent); // Bind event listener with 'input' event and 'titleEvent' function.

  cityInput.addEventListener('input', cityEvent);
}

var originalJSONArr = [
  {
    title: 'Taiwan',
    city: 'Taipei City'
  },
  {
    title: 'Taiwan',
    city: 'Taichung'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'New York'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'Chicago'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'Miami'
  },
  {
    title: 'USA',
    city: 'Boston'
  }
];

addEventListeners(
  function(values) { // This is the 'filterJSON' callback as mentioned.
    var filteredJSON = originalJSONArr.filter(function(item) {
      return (item.title === values.title || item.city === values.city);
    });
    // You can do anything with filteredJSON as of here.
    console.log(filteredJSON);
  }
);
```

```html
Title:<br>
<input id="title" type="text" name="title"><br>
City:<br>
<input id="city" type="text" name="city">
```